# Toolbar overlapping other widgets in layout

Tags: android, xml

I'm making an app where I'm using `ConstraintLayout`. However when I add toolbar it overlaps other components. I'm using constraint layout for this purpose I've seen other questions on so but they are not using `ConstraintLayout`.
Is there something that I'm missing in `ConstraintLayout` because all other questions on SO are using `CoordinatorLayout`

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

mainactiivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Work">

        <include layout="@layout/activity_toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputfrom"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="From"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/texttypetravel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/inpuTo"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inpuTo"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="182dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Destination"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texttypetravel"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="455dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Work"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spinner"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputfrom" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="236dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputdescription"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputdescription"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="119dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Work Description"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBoxTrain"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxExpense"
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Expense Given"
            android:onClick="enable"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBoxpass"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/inputExpenseGiven"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputExpenseGiven"
            android:layout_width="195dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Amount"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputamount1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxpass"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Pass Taken"
            android:onClick="passtaken"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBoxTrain"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxTrain"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Train"
            android:onClick="train"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputamount2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputdescription" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxBus"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Bus"
            android:onClick="bus"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBoxTrain" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxBike"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Bike"
            android:onClick="bikeEnable"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/inputamount3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBoxBus" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxShareRickShaw"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:onClick="shareRickshaw"
            android:text="Share RickShaw"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBoxBike" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="passgiven"
            android:maxWidth="30dip"
            android:maxHeight="50dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/inputamount1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inpuTo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="trainticketimage"
            android:maxWidth="30dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/inputamount2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputamount1"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputamount2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputamount2"
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="68dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputamount3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBoxBus"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBoxTrain" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputamount3"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputamount4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputamount2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputamount4"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_submit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.272"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBoxShareRickShaw"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputamount3" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="199dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:maxWidth="30dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="busticketimage"
            android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/inputamount3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="submit_btn"
            android:text="Submit"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textfinalamount"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.229"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputamount4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textfinalamount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAvailableBalance"
            android:layout_width="187dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Available Balance"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.081"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputamount4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAvailableBalance1"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="3000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_submit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.514"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textAvailableBalance" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textbalanceused"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Used Money"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textfinalamount"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_submit"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textAvailableBalance1"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` remove from your editform ediitext and create id for include layout. then set top to bottom of edittext text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  remove `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` from inputform and inputo, and add `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"` in both.

try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Work">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/activity_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputfrom"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="From"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/texttypetravel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/inpuTo"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inpuTo"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="182dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Destination"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texttypetravel"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="455dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Work"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spinner"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputfrom" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="236dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputdescription"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputdescription"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="119dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Work Description"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBoxTrain"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxExpense"
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Expense Given"
            android:onClick="enable"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBoxpass"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/inputExpenseGiven"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputExpenseGiven"
            android:layout_width="195dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Amount"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputamount1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxpass"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Pass Taken"
            android:onClick="passtaken"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBoxTrain"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxTrain"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Train"
            android:onClick="train"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputamount2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputdescription" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxBus"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Bus"
            android:onClick="bus"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBoxTrain" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxBike"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Bike"
            android:onClick="bikeEnable"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/inputamount3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBoxBus" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxShareRickShaw"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:onClick="shareRickshaw"
            android:text="Share RickShaw"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBoxBike" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="passgiven"
            android:maxWidth="30dip"
            android:maxHeight="50dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/inputamount1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inpuTo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="trainticketimage"
            android:maxWidth="30dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/inputamount2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputamount1"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputamount2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputamount2"
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="68dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputamount3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBoxBus"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBoxTrain" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputamount3"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputamount4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputamount2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputamount4"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_submit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.272"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBoxShareRickShaw"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputamount3" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="199dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:maxWidth="30dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="busticketimage"
            android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/inputamount3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="submit_btn"
            android:text="Submit"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textfinalamount"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.229"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputamount4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textfinalamount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAvailableBalance"
            android:layout_width="187dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Available Balance"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.081"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputamount4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAvailableBalance1"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="3000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_submit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.514"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textAvailableBalance" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textbalanceused"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Used Money"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textfinalamount"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_submit"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textAvailableBalance1"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: but other views are losing place like when i resize edittext to fit into screen text is not visible and so for the other edittexts

Comment: When you resize edittext you have to consider other views also. My answer only defines the positions  of inputform and inputo. (below toolbar)

Comment: absolutely sir your solution is working fine but i wanted to know how do i fit the views in screen so that other vies are not affected because i'm facing isuue of fiiting everything onscreen at once

Comment: Any suggestion you may have plaese let me know

Comment: Rearranging views in a  `ConstraintLayout` its really hard.It will affect other views. In my case, I will remove all constraints then rearrange views. At last I will give constraints to views one by one

Comment: adding constraint is the most difficult part even if i remove constraints arrange views it is very difficult to add constraint in lower places and if do infer constraint it messes up the entire layout

Answer (score 0):

Your inputFrom and toolbar both have the constraint app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" and they both have the same parent.  Try making the inputFrom go to the bottom of the toolbar.

Comment: when i'm adding constraint app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="activity/toolbar" in inputForm other view are getting affected drastically

Comment: i'm trying to use constraint layout for every layout